# Class with function pointer that can call multiple kind of functions in different instantiations

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers

I'm writing something like a button in SDL, that can do something if I interact with it. I want to store every button in one container (in something like a list or deque), so I can call their own draw functions, and I can also check which one I clicked at. So, I thought the easiest way is to instantiate them from a generic class ("Button") so all of them will have a position, color etc etc, and also a function pointer which I can set to a custom function when I instantiate them.

My problem is that when I define the function pointer in the class, I have to declare an argument list, but there can be cases when I will need a different argument list (e.g.:

```
MyButton button() 
button.fooptr=quit; //quit is a void function with no arguments
button.fooptr();
//another case
button.fooptr=print; //print is a void function which takes an SDL_Surface* as an argument.
button.fooptr(screen);
```

I've tried to define the function pointer as a `void (*fooptr)(...)`, which works wonderfully if my function has (...) as argument, but if I try to call the function with `fooptr(screen)`, the function can't see the screen variable I pass to it. Is there any solution to be able to pass a custom amount of arguments to specific functions, and pass zero arguments to functions with no arguments?

Comment: This doesn't sound very safe.  What would happen if you did `fooptr = print; fooptr();`?

Comment: `MyButton button()` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What, you don't think Brabulla wanted a function called `button` that returns an instance of `MyButton`?  Maybe Brabulla just forgot the `()` on each line afterwards...  ;)

Comment: @Brabulla When do you know the `screen` parameter -- do you know what it is going to be when you assign `fooptr=print`?  (You'll note that in your example, you could delete all mention of `fooptr` and just call `quit()` and `print(screen)` directly: you have an implied gap of time between setting up the pointer and calling the function.  What I'm asking is what the connection is between the point where the function pointer is assigned, and the point where it is called -- there clearly has to be SOME connection, or how would you know how many arguments to pass?)

Comment: @Yakk: Nope! You can't use a temporary as an lvalue. `struct T { int x; }; T foo() { return T(); } int main() { foo().x = 3; } // error:  using temporary as lvalue`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `typedef MyRealButton& MyButton;` obviously.

Comment: @Brabulla oh, and what is your compiler and version?  Do you have access to any C++11 features?

Comment: @Yakk: you obviously know how to push my buttons

Comment: @Yakk I'm using the built in compiler of Code::blocks, a GNU GCC 4.7. And to your older question: I don't know the arguments and values of the function at the point of assigning, I will only know them when I intend to use it. E.G. like a menu, where I put down some buttons right at the start of the program, then, later on I might click on a button to open something (e.g an options window) where i do something, then I close it and return to the original area.

Comment: @Brabulla So you know when you push the button that this button has a function that takes a particular argument.  How do you know that, and yet not know *which* function you are calling?  You appear to have two different bits of code that independently have to know exactly what this button does, the part where you build the button, and the part where you call it.  (There are answers to that, but the answer to that determines the best solution, which rarely is a `void*`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual C way is to have a void* argument that can be NULL or can point to a structure where the content lives. The called function casts it to the proper structure type and access the elements.

For a C++ std::bind and std::function might help you.

If you really want to go with simple functions, you can check out proper [va_arg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_arg/) usage, (I think) you need at least one argument to start accessing the rest, and the function can struggle its way processing them.   Note that ... is restricted to POD argument types.

Comment: In the end I went with this solution. I think I won't use any complex functions, so a va_list should be enough, and also this is a quite easy solution, which doesn't really require huge expansion headers, though this might not be the best solution, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The way you have described defining and calling the functions is not very safe. This is because as Oli noted in their comment it is quite easy to call the function incorrectly. If the target function expects 3 arguments and you end up passing only 1 you get undefined behavior and anything can happen. In this case that "anything" is going to be something bad.

If you know the arguments ahead of time you can use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and early binding of parameters to call the function in a much safer way. This will allow you to create a function object at the point where you [should] *know* what parameters need to be passed, bind the parameters and then set `fooptr`.

The example below uses the code from your question and expands on it using `std::bind` and `std::function` to call the functions in a safe uniform manner. It also includes an example of using [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) to allow passing a parameter by reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct SDLSurface 
{
    std::string str;
};

struct Button
{
    std::function<void(void)> fooptr;
};

void quit()
{
    std::cout << "called quit()" << std::endl;
}

void print(SDLSurface *surface)
{
    std::cout << "called print(\"" << surface->str << "\")" << std::endl;
}

void print_string(const std::string& str)
{
    std::cout << "called print_string(\"" << str << "\")" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Button>> buttons;
    std::unique_ptr<Button> b;

    // Create a button and assign a function that takes no parameters
    b.reset(new Button());
    b->fooptr = quit;
    buttons.push_back(std::move(b));

    // Create a button and assign a function
    b.reset(new Button());
    SDLSurface  surface;
    b->fooptr = std::bind(print, &surface);
    buttons.push_back(std::move(b));

    // Create a button and assign a function taking a parameter by reference
    b.reset(new Button());
    std::string string_param;
    // Since we are passing by reference and want to bind to an existing variable
    // we need to use a reference wrapper.
    b->fooptr = std::bind(
        print_string,
        std::reference_wrapper<const std::string>(string_param));
    buttons.push_back(std::move(b));

    // Call all functions setting the value of string_param before we do.
    surface.str = "hello";
    string_param = "world";
    for(auto it = buttons.begin(); it != buttons.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->fooptr();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The press of the button is an event that should contain basic information (take a look at the callbacks/events in existing frameworks/languages) The interface of the base button should only support that particular use case. If you need some particular type of button to call a different type of function, then that needs to be handled differently. One option would be using `std::bind` to adapt the interfaces of the event that is triggered (in the simplest form no args) and the function to be called (inject the surface).

```
struct Button {
   std::function<void()> callback;

   void pressed() { callback(); }
   void register(std::function<void()> const &cb) {
      callback = cb; 
   }
};
struct ButtonWithSurface : Button {
...
    SDLSurface *surface;
    void register(std::function<void(SDLSurface*)> const &cb) {
       Button::register(std::bind(cb,surface);
    }
```

From all users of the base `Button` the operation that can be executed is *pressing* the button, although in the `ButtonWithSurface` case that will trigger a call to a function that takes a `SDLSurface*` argument. Still, users need not know that detail, as that is handled only during registration of the callback that is done with the concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with closures (and don't want to learn about them), define function objects:

```
class BtnFunctional {
public:
    virtual void Call () = 0;
    virtual ~BtnFunctional () {
    }
};

class QuitBtnFunctional : public BtnFunctional {
public:
    virtual void Call () {
        // call quit function
    }
};

class PrintBtnFunctional : public BtnFunctional {
private:
    ScreenType * theScreen;
public:
    PrintBtnFunctional (ScreenType * screen) : theScreen (screen) {
    }

    virtual void Call () {
        // call print function, e.g. print (theScreen);
    }
};

// ...
btn.fooptr = new QuitBtnFunctional ();
btn.fooptr.Call ();
btn.fooptr = new PrintBtnFunctional (screen);
btn.fooptr.Call ();
```

Be careful: The objects should be destroyed somewhere, i.e. you should use smart pointers to store them!